# Selenium: reuse of found elements for child in Wait of Expected_conditions

Tags: python, selenium

How in Selenium can reuse of found elements for a child in `Wait` of Expected_conditions?

Example html:

```
<p class="some">1<p>
<div class="content">
   <p class="other">2<p>
   <p class="some">3<p>
</div>
```

In simple cases can use:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.content')
elem.find_element_by_css_selector('p.some')
```

But something like this does not works:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.content')))
elem.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.some')))
```

Unfortunately, for now I have to write a full selector path in Wait everytime. It is not comfortable.

Comment: You can't call `wait` as a instance method of `elem`. One way to do is to store all the elements you need to find in a `page_object.py` and then import it as a module and reuse elements whenever.

Comment: Could you write example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
elem =  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.content')))
psome = wait.until(lambda d:elem.find_element_by_css_selector('p.some'))
```

Note: I haven't actually tried it in Python, but I used similar technique in C# and Java quite a lot, so unless I have some minor syntactic mistakes, I'm pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Without going into too much details, lambda is like an inner function. Wait.until calls this function repeatedly until it returns anything other than nil and doesn't throw an exception. In fact, all of the expected_condition methods return functions like this.